# add a route, google is unedfined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, maps, undefined

I try to add a simple route in my map but when i call google.maps.DirectionsService() i get this google is undefined, so i try to add a const variable but now the error message is Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined..

I don't know what im doing wrong

```
const google = window.google;

class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0,
            nombre_de_bars: null
        }
    }
    map() {
        const [selectedBar, setSelectedBar] = useState(null);
        const { nombre_de_bars } = this.state

        const rows = nombre_de_bars.map(bar =>
            <Marker key={bar._id}
                position={{
                    lat: bar.latitude,
                    lng: bar.longitude
                }}
                onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedBar(bar);
                }}
                icon={{
                    url: '/images/biere_logo.png',
                    scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                }}
            />
        );
        return (
            <GoogleMap
                defaultZoom={14}
                defaultCenter={{ lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude }}
                defaultOptions={{
                    zoomControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    rotateControl: false,
                    fullscreenControl: false
                }}>
                <Marker
                    position={{ lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude }}
                    icon={{
                        url: '/images/marker.png',
                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(50, 50)
                    }}
                />
                {rows}
                {selectedBar && (
                    <InfoWindow
                        position={{
                            lat: selectedBar.latitude,
                            lng: selectedBar.longitude
                        }}
                        onCloseClick={() => {
                            setSelectedBar(null);
                        }}
                    >
                        <div>
                            <p>{selectedBar.name}</p>
                            <p>{selectedBar.description}</p>
                            <button onClick={() => {
                                this.itineraireTo(selectedBar);
                            }}>Je m'y rend</button>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow>
                )}
            </GoogleMap>
        );
    }
    render() {
        const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(this.map.bind(this)));
        const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        return (
            <WrappedMap
                googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
                loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%`, width: '100%' }} />}
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%`, width: '100%' }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%`, width: '100%' }} />}

            />
        );
    }
}
export default Map;
```

I try to export with withGoogleMap(Map) but not fix the problem.

I read the documentation on tomchentw.github.io but not the similar problem was occured

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a global variable which is not defined. Make sure you the Google Maps script has been loaded before your app starts, or wait for it to be available in your component.

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this from our side?